# App crashing on Android API less than 5.0(lollipop)

Tags: android, sdk, android-gradle-plugin, build-tools

The problem I am facing is that my android application works well on devices having API 5.0 and above but crashes on devices having Kitkat(4.4) and its corresponding lower versions.I know that its somehow related to the build tools in my gradle file,but still not able to figure out the problem.Could someone please help me out with this.

This is my gradle file,

```
     buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
apply plugin: 'android'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    maven { url 'http://clinker.47deg.com/nexus/content/groups/public' }
}


android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion '22.0.1'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.abc.example"
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 22
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionCode 12
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            multiDexEnabled true
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    android {
        packagingOptions {
            exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        }
    }
    android {
        packagingOptions {
            exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        }
    }
}



dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
    compile('com.fortysevendeg.swipelistview:swipelistview:1.0-SNAPSHOT@aar') {
        transitive = true
        exclude module: 'httpclient'
        exclude group: 'httpclient'
    }

    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:mockwebserver:2.3.0'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:1.2.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:7.5.0'
    compile files('libs/bitlyj-2.0.0.jar')

}
```

Also getting this error when project is built,

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.package.R$styleable
            at com.package.widgets.StyleableTextView.<init>(StyleableTextView.java:23)
```

This is StyleableTextView class,

```
public class StyleableTextView extends TextView {

    public StyleableTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public StyleableTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context.getApplicationContext(), attrs);
        UiUtil.setCustomFont(StyleableTextView.this, context, attrs,
                R.styleable.com_eywa_wonk_widgets_StyleableTextView,
                R.styleable.com_eywa_wonk_widgets_StyleableTextView_font);
    }

    public StyleableTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context.getApplicationContext(), attrs, defStyle);
        UiUtil.setCustomFont(StyleableTextView.this, context, attrs,
                R.styleable.com_eywa_wonk_widgets_StyleableTextView,
                R.styleable.com_eywa_wonk_widgets_StyleableTextView_font);
    }

}
```

This is the styleable in attrs,

```
<resources>

    <attr name="font" format="string" />

<declare-styleable name="com.package.widgets.StyleableTextView">
        <attr name="font" />

    </declare-styleable>

</resources>
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about the error ? Post the stack trace

Comment: Yeah sure.I have created a custom styleable for a custom textview in my attrs file in "values" folder.The styleable gets detected in devices having 5.0 but in devices with API 4.4 and less, it says cannot find the custom TextView in your app along with the <declare-styleable /> error and I am pretty sure i have used it as "com.package.CustomTextView"

Comment: Does the values folder have a version counter? Such as /values-v22? If so, you will need to make something for other versions, or add the custom styleable only for Lollipop devices.

Comment: @Knossos no it doesn't have a version counter..

Comment: @forcewill I have updated the post with its error stack.Please have a look.

Comment: @Knossos updated the post a little please can you take a look.?

Comment: @Androidsolutions does the error occurs in release, debug or both ? Can you post the declare-styleable  also ?

Comment: Yes I can post that..and yes it occurs in all builds be it debug or release and if I remove multiDexEnabled="true" build fails with error "non zero exit value as 2".

Comment: @forcewill updated the post with the declare-styleable.Please do have a look.

Comment: I don't know if this could be the cause but you're using plugin `android` and plugin `com.android.application` plugin 'android' is deprecated and you should use only the later maybe something on the build is going wrong because you have both, try and remove android one

Comment: @forcewill will try that as well..

Answer (score 27, accepted):

When you are using `multidex` , then try to extend your application class with `MultiDexAppication` instead of `Application` and override below method this required for Android below 5.0 (because 5.0 and above support to the multidex)

```
   @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context base)
    {
        super.attachBaseContext(base);
        MultiDex.install(BaseApplication.this);
    }
```

and in dependencies add this
   **compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'**

Comment: Man, this post is a life saver. I had been looking for a solution for 2 days. I wasn't sure of the issue either.

Answer (score 3):

I just had this problem and solved it by adding the following line to the applications AndroidManifest.xml as an attribute on the application tag:

```
android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
```

I have two apps which share the same resources and libraries. The only difference is in the exposed interface. I added multidex to both but forgot to put the above attribute in the manifest for one. The NoClassDefFoundError did not help much at all.

You can also check out the following:
http://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html

Answer (score 0):

One issue that you may face is this one, as [explained in the documentation](https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html#limitations):

```
multiDexEnabled true
```

> Applications that use multidex may not start on devices that run
>   versions of the platform earlier than Android 4.0 (API level 14) due
>   to a Dalvik linearAlloc bug (Issue 22586). If you are targeting API
>   levels earlier than 14, make sure to perform testing with these
>   versions of the platform as your application can have issues at
>   startup or when particular groups of classes are loaded. Code
>   shrinking can reduce or possibly eliminate these potential issues.

Comment: when multiDexEnabled removed then build encounters an error as "Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 2"

Answer (score 0):

This might not be relevant to the particular scenario but as the heading of the question relates to the problem I encountered and the reason I came across this question. So I am answering it here. 
I encountered an issue similar to this, but in my case extending multidexapplication, and enabling multidex weren't doing the job. I ended up using a [plugin](http://www.methodscount.com/plugins) for counting methods in my project. By using that I realised that I am no way near the 65K limit and the bug is related to something else. I found [this](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=199327) page where they someone had talked about disabling instant-run from Settings, which actually did the job for me. Now I am not using the multi-dex library and the builds are faster as well. If I encounter the issue again, I will update the answer accordingly.