# multidex crash below 5.0

Tags: android

my application working fine with 5.0 and above but if i intall in bewow 5.0 it crah after i use multidex library

```
    android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"

         defaultConfig {
             minSdkVersion 14 //lower than 14 doesn't support multidex
             targetSdkVersion 22

             // Enabling multidex support.
             multiDexEnabled true
         }
    }

    dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    }


    public class MyApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    protected void OnCreate(Context base) {
          MultiDex.install(this);
     }

   }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [App crashing on Android API less than 5.0(lollipop)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32328806/app-crashing-on-android-api-less-than-5-0lollipop)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
public class MyApplication extends MultidexApplication {

@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
    super.attachBaseContext(base);
    MultiDex.install(this);
}

}
```

try this .

Answer (score -2):

Before `MultiDex.install(this);` in onCreate() call super.onCreate(...)

Comment: i alredy use this in my code but it crash below 5.0